# How To Continuously Deliver database changes within devops pipeline

Tags: mysql, database, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, devops

What are good resources to look at for adding mysql changes to our devops pipeline?

We are in process of standing up a CI/CD pipeline where we are automatically building, configuring and deploying software to servers.

We currently can deploy an application to a blank server but are taking a snapshot of a database to populate the data (essentially unpacking an existing database). We do not want to move data from enviornmnet to environment. We also do not want our database updates in all environments to be a manual process.

We would like to have some automated process to move database changes along with the code in some automated fashion, And keep the ability to deploy our application to a server and have the database be populated with the necessary data to have a run able application.

Comment: use liquibase or flyway

Comment: I'm a liquibase fan, myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of a few resources to help you understand how to make database changes in a deployment pipeline.

- [Enabling Continuous Delivery with Database Practices from about 25 minutes](https://vimeo.com/111623115)
- [Continuous Deployment at Etsy slides 50+ give an example of making a change to a schema](http://www.slideshare.net/mikebrittain/mbrittain-continuous-deploymentalm3public)